# A way to connect checkbox state to widget visibility in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

Does anyone know if there is a way to connect a state of a checkbox in Qt to an object visibility in Qt Designer? I somewhat new to Qt and and prefer to work with Qt Designer rather than messing with the UI code manually. Qt version I'm using is 4.8.6

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In code (old Qt 4 way):

```
connect(checkbox, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), widget, SLOT(setVisible(bool)));
```

or (recommended Qt 5 way):

```
connect(checkbox, QCheckBox::toggled, widget, YourWidgetType::setVisible);
```

In Designer: open the Signals And Slots Editor, connect signal and slot above.

Noticed that signals and slots from Designer are reset sometimes, don't know why. Maybe it is more reliable to connect them in code on widgets setup.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can connect the checkbox's `toggled(bool)` signal to the widget's `setVisible(bool)` or `setHidden(bool)` slot in Qt Designer - either in "Edit Signals/Slots" mode using drag-and-drop, or in the "Signal/Slot Editor" dock.

If using the drag-and-drop interface to add the connection, you'll need to turn on "Show signals and slots inherited from QWidget", else `setVisible(bool)` and `setHidden(bool)` will not be available for the target widget.